# Create a DLL using Makefile to run on Windows XP (32 bit) and Windows 7 (64 bit)

Tags: windows, dll, makefile

I need to modify the below makefile to create a dll (SampleNew.dll) that will run on a 32-bit windows and 64-bit Windows environment.  Maybe creating two dlls (one for 64 and one for 32) is the best approach. It needs to use SampleApi.dll (in LIBS declaration below). The below doesn't create a valid 32 bit dll for Windows.  Any ideas on how to modify the below to make it work?

```
CMODE=

SWIG = swig
CC = $(PREFIX)gcc
LD = $(CC) 

OBJ_DIR = obj
AUTOGEN_DIR = ../src/java
PACKAGE_DIR = $(AUTOGEN_DIR)/com/test/sample

PACKAGE = com.test.sample

INCLUDES = -I$(JAVA_INCLUDE) \
           -I$(SAMPLE_DIR)/include \
           -I$(JDK_HOME)/include

LIB_INCLUDES = -L$(SAMPLE_DIR)/lib

LIBS = /lib/libssl.so.4 \
       /lib/libcrypto.so.4 \
       -lSampleApi \
       -lm

DIRS = $(PACKAGE_DIR) $(DIST_DIR) $(OBJ_DIR) $(AUTOGEN_DIR)

CFLAGS = $(CMODE) -Wall -fpic $(INCLUDES) -O0 -g3
SFLAGS = -java $(INCLUDES) -package $(PACKAGE) -outdir $(PACKAGE_DIR)
LDFLAGS = -shared $(LIB_INCLUDES) $(LIBS)

OBJECTS = $(OBJ_DIR)/test_wrap.o
TARGET = $(LIB_DIR)/SampleNew.dll

all: $(DIRS) $(TARGET)

%_wrap.c: %.i
    $(SWIG) $(SFLAGS) $< 

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(LD) $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

$(DIRS):
    mkdir -p $@

clean:
    rm -rf $(TARGET) $(PACKAGE_DIR)/* $(TARGET) $(AUTOGEN_DIR) $(OBJ_DIR)
```

**Exception:**

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError c:\test\myDllFile.dll: can't load this .dll (machine code=0x101) on a IA 32-bit platform
```

**update Makefile:**

```
CMODE=

SWIG = swig
PREFIX=/test/mingw/mingw32/bin/i386-mingw32-
CC = $(PREFIX)gcc
LD = $(CC) 

OBJ_DIR = obj
AUTOGEN_DIR = ../src/java
PACKAGE_DIR = $(AUTOGEN_DIR)/com/test/jni

PACKAGE = com.test.jni

INCLUDES = -I$(HEADER_FILES_DIR) # env var that points to a dir with all the .h files

LIB_INCLUDES = -L$(C_API_DIR)/lib # env var that points to a dir with the C libraries (dlls)

LIBS = -lMainApi \ # MainApi.dll
       -lm

DIRS = $(PACKAGE_DIR) $(DIST_DIR) $(OBJ_DIR) $(AUTOGEN_DIR) # DIST_DIR is passed in 

CFLAGS = $(CMODE) -Wall -fpic $(INCLUDES) -O0 -g3
SFLAGS = -java $(INCLUDES) -package $(PACKAGE) -outdir $(PACKAGE_DIR)
LDFLAGS = -shared $(LIB_INCLUDES) $(LIBS) -leay32 -lws2_32 -lrpcrt4

OBJECTS = $(OBJ_DIR)/test_wrap.o
TARGET = $(LIB_DIR)/SampleJni.dll

all: $(DIRS) $(TARGET)

%_wrap.c: %.i
    $(SWIG) $(SFLAGS) $< 

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(LD) $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

$(DIRS):
    mkdir -p $@

clean:
    rm -rf $(TARGET) $(PACKAGE_DIR)/* $(TARGET) $(AUTOGEN_DIR) $(OBJ_DIR)
```

Comment: A 32-bit DLL will run on 64-bit versions of Windows...

Comment: @todda.speot.is: But only if the main program is also 32-bit.

Comment: I'm a bit confused - is it C or Java? And in any case, if your DLL uses another existing DLL (SampleApi.dll), you can only compile it to be the same (e.g. 32 bit) as SampleApi.dll, otherwise the two can't reside in the same process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing you can do is to build both separately. For example, defining:

```
CFLAGS = $(CMODE) -Wall -fpic $(INCLUDES) -O0 -g3 -march=$(ARCH)
OBJ_DIR = obj-$(ARCH)
LIB_DIR = lib-$(ARCH)

.PHONY: default
default:
        $(MAKE) ARCH=i686 all
        $(MAKE) ARCH=x86_64 all
```

Avoid `-m32`, since it generates 32bit code for x86-64, which may use instructions not available in x86.

Comment: My understanding is that for x86/x64 architectures, -m32 allows for the building of 32 bit applications using the 64 bit tool chain, and that such applications will run on x86 hardware just fine.  Can you provide a reference that states otherwise?

Comment: It just instructs GCC to use 32bit code, but it's expected to support anything x86_64 allows, plus when using `-Ox` it optimizes with a very unconvenient alignment. Some x86 implementations lack the SYS* and CMOV* instructions, that will be a problem. BTW, the 64bit toolchain is a superset of the 32bit one, so you should be able to use -march=i686 without troubles.

Comment: OK - I had to look this one up.  According to the GCC man page: "-m32/-m64 - Generate code for a 32-bit or 64-bit environment. The 32-bit environment sets int, long and pointer to 32 bits and generates code that runs on any i386 system. The 64-bit environment sets int to 32 bits and long and pointer to 64 bits and generates code for AMD 's x86-64 architecture. For darwin only the -m64 option turns off the -fno-pic and -mdynamic-no-pic options."

Comment: The man page is wrong, but don't believe me, just run: `cpp -m32 -dM /dev/null`, see? It's identifying the architecture as K8 (`__k8__`).

Comment: @Ismael - thanks for the response.  I'm running this on a 32 bit linux instal.  I tried to build a dll for windows XP but I still get the same error as in my first post. I'm not 100% sure what to take from your example and plug in my makefile above.  Can you help me identify what I need to change to create a dll that works for a 32 bit windows machine (windows xp) and then the changes for a 64 bit dll for windows 7?

Comment: @c12 - first, could you post the output when running the makefile?

Comment: As for my example, the trick is adding `-march=$(ARCH)` to `CFLAGS`, so that you can call `make ARCH=cpu`. Changing `OBJ_DIR` and `LIB_DIR` is convenient so you can build both targets on the same tree, which is what the `all` target does.

Comment: @Ismael - I added the exception I was getting above.  I made some changes as was able to get Java (on Windows XP) to load the Makefile generated dll file.  Do you see any issues with how I've changed the Makefile?

Comment: First, you need to use MinGW with 64bit support (which isn't official), in order to compile for both architectures, and if it is not still clear, you _must_ build two dlls (AFAIK, windows doesn't support multi-architecture executables), thus you need to build it twic, with different flags, as in my example snippet.

Comment: Also, `-l` parameters in `LDFLAGS` should go into `LIBS` (consistency issue).

Answer (score 1):

Your tool chain will have to support both bitnesses; your compiler and linker will have to be able to emit both 64-bit and 32-bit code, or you could have two separate tool chains. Let's assume your compiler is in 64-bit mode by default and takes a switch to create 32-bit code. You can use target-specific variables in `make` to set this switch for the 32-bit build.
Besides the compiler, you will also have to set some other variables differently for the two builds. Things that come to mind are `OBJ_DIR` and `LIB_DIR`, so the output files don't mix; `LIB_INCLUDES`, because both builds require their own versions of the libraries you're linking against (so you will need two versions of `SampleApi.dll`).

Your makefile will come to look something along these lines:

```
32bit: CC           += -m32
32bit: OBJ_DIR       = obj32
32bit: LIB_DIR      := $(LIB_DIR)32
32bit: LIB_INCLUDES  = -L$(SAMPLE_DIR)/lib32

all: 64bit 32bit

64bit 32bit: $(DIRS) $(TARGET)
```

(I've excluded the parts that don't need to change.)